# Why is my gatsby website's main thread so slow?

Tags: performance, optimization, gatsby, lighthouse

My main-thread is 6.1sec long based on light house. My website is https://ali126191.github.io/charity-project-starter/

Light house main thead results:

Category Time Spent

Script Evaluation 2,267 m\s

Style & Layout 1,095 ms

Other 1,053 ms

Script Parsing & Compilation 757 ms

Parse HTML & CSS  536 ms

Garbage Collection 273 ms

Rendering   78 ms

I thought gatsby did code splitting so my website should be pretty fast and this would not be a issue. I am a beginner, so I do not understand much about these things.